# a conversion error where it says no conversion from "char*" to char

Tags: c++, type-conversion

**This is my .h, header file**

```
#ifndef KINGDOM_H_
#define KINGDOM_H_

namespace westeros {

    class Kingdom {
    public:
        char m_name[32];
        int m_population;

    };

    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomElement, char nameOfKingdom);

}
#endif
```

**This is my .cpp, source file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "kingdom.h"
using namespace std;

namespace westeros{


    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomElement, char nameOfKingdom){

        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < kingdomElement; i++) {
            **if(pKingdom[i].m_name == nameOfKingdom){** //it's giving me error right here, visual studio underlining red line below == sign saying operand types are incompatible 
                cout << "Searching for kingdom " << pKingdom[i].m_name << " in Westeros " << endl;
                cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
                cout << pKingdom[i].m_name << ", population " << pKingdom[i].m_population << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
                cout << "Searching for kingdom " << nameOfKingdom << " in Westeros " << endl;
                cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
                cout << nameOfKingdom << " is not part of Westeros." << endl;
                cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and this is my main file trying to call it**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "kingdom.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace westeros;

int main(void)

{

    int count = 0; // the number of kingdoms in the array

    Kingdom* pKingdoms = nullptr;

    //allocating dynamic memory
    pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];

    display(pKingdoms, count, "Mordor");
    cout << endl;

    display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale");
    cout << endl;
    delete[]pKingdoms;
    pKingdoms = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone find what could be the problem?

Comment: You are confused about the difference between a `char` and a string.  A `char` is a single character (for example, a letter).

Comment: oh so char nameOfKingdom means it can only accept a single letter? which type would I use then?

Comment: Big hint in what aschepler said: "the difference between a `char` and a string[.]" Two types in that statement, and you've already found `char` didn't work.

Comment: because what I am trying to do at the if statement is, checking if the Kingdom with the specified name exists in array how display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale") is trying to check if the kingdom named The_Vale exists in the array or not

Comment: But the function parameter is declared as `char nameOfKingdom`. This is a *single* character. How did you plan to specify the kingdom's name by a single character? Everywhere else you are using char arrays to specify names. But here it is suddenly just a single character. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `pKingdom[i].m_name` is a `char[32]`, and the type of `nameOfKingdom` is `char`. You cannot compare a character array with a character.

> which type would I use then?

`std::string`

Comment: I fixed the type problem, but now it won't work the way I wanted it to be. The Vale should be in the part of westeros since it is in the array and should be printed out like this pKingdom[i].m_name << ", population " << pKingdom[i].m_population << endl; when it prints out as if it didn't exist in the array. So i am guessing the if condition has some kind of problem. Do you mind helping

Comment: @GodCoder I guess you didn't follow @user2079303 advice to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and as a consequence you are comparing adresses. And I'll add: use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of `new []`.

Comment: no but i did use the string though, void display (Kingdom kingdom[], int kingdomElement, string nameOfKingdom) and it still does not work

Comment: @GodCoder See my answer done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948958/if-statement-is-not-working-and-is-skipped-to-else-part/41949203#41949203).