# if statement is not working and is skipped to else part

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
//this is my source file, .cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "kingdom.h"
namespace westeros{
    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomElement, string KingdomName){
        cout << " ---------------- " << endl;
        cout << " Searching for kingdom " << KingdomName << " in westeros " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<kingdomElement; i++){
            if (pKingdom[i].m_name == KingdomName){
                cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
                cout << KingdomName << ", population " << pKingdom[i].m_population << endl;
                cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
            }

            else{
                cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
                cout << KingdomName << " is not part of Westeros. " << endl;
                cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
//this is my main file
#include <iostream>
#include "kingdom.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace westeros;

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    Kingdom* pKingdoms = nullptr;
    pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];
    display(pKingdoms, count, "Mordor");
    display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale");
    delete[]pKingdoms;
    pKingdoms = nullptr;
    return 0;
}

//this is my header file
#ifndef KINGDOM_H_
#define KINGDOM_H_
using namespace std;
namespace westeros{
    class Kingdom{
    public:
        char m_name[32];
        int m_population;  
    };
    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomElement, string KingdomName);
}
#endif
```

Now it prints

The Mordor is not part of Westeros
The Mordor is not part of Westeros
The Mordor is not part of Westeros
The Mordor is not part of Westeros
The Mordor is not part of Westeros

The_Vale is not part of Westeros
The_Vale, population 234567
The_Vale is not part of Westeros
The_Vale is not part of Westeros
The_Vale is not part of Westeros

Comment: `pKingdom[kingdomElement]` is accessing outside the bounds of the allocated memory.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You call `new Kingdom[count]`, then pass that allocated memory and `count` to `display`.  You're then accessing element `Kingdom[count]` (since `kingdomElement` the same value as `count`), which is outside of the memory you allocated which results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: so how could I fix it to make it work?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that `if` statement. But just keep in mind that array indexing starts at `0`. So `count` is out of bounds.

Comment: `pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];`  `count` is 0 at this point, so you create an array of size 0.

Comment: i declared a variable inside the void function int, and i initialized it to 0, so it looks like int i = 0; and I replaced kingdomElement to i but it still don't work so it looks like this if (pKingdom[i].m_name == KingdomName)

Comment: Where are you adding elements into your `Kingdom` array?

Comment: Note that this syntax `new Kingdom[count];` is performing default init which means all those `Kingdom` elements have an indeterminate value since you don't have a constructor(ignoring the fact that `count` is 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just forgot to add the `The_Vale` to the `pKingdoms` array.

So, something like this will make you understand what did you do wrong:

In the main file you can improve it like below, all other files are okay ;)

```
    //this is my main file
  #include <iostream>
  #include "kingdom.h"
  #include <string.h>
  using namespace std;
  using namespace westeros;

  int main(void){
      int count = 0;

      // Kingdom* pKingdoms = nullptr;
      // pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];
      Kingdom* pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];   // Might be a better choice,
                                          // as it reduces code.

      display(pKingdoms, count, "Mordor");      // pKingdoms doesn't have Mordor
      display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale");    // pKingdoms doesn't have The_vale

      // Here I add the 'The_Vale to the array 
      strcpy(pKingdoms[0].m_name, "The_Vale");
      pKingdoms[0].m_population = 1000;

      display(pKingdoms, count, "The_Vale");    // pKingdoms have The_vale

      delete[]pKingdoms;
      pKingdoms = nullptr;
      return 0;
  }
```

Also after edit, maybe something like this in source.cpp will help.

```
//this is my source file, .cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "kingdom.h"
namespace westeros{
    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomElement, string KingdomName){
      int flag = -1;
        cout << " ---------------- " << endl;
        cout << " Searching for kingdom " << KingdomName << " in westeros " << endl;

        for(int i=0; i<kingdomElement; i++)
            if (pKingdom[i].m_name == KingdomName)
                flag = i;

        if (flag != -1)
        {
            cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
            cout << KingdomName << ", population " << pKingdom[flag].m_population << endl;
            cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
        }

        else{
              cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
              cout << KingdomName << " is not part of Westeros. " << endl;
              cout << " --------------------- " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just right now, I added a for loop for(int i=0; i<kingdomElement; i++){} right below cout << " Searching for kingdom " << KingdomName << " in westeros " << endl; I get the right message, but I get too much repetition of messages

Comment: after puting for loop, I get Mordor is not part of Westeros 5 times because thats my count number and I get The_Vale is not part of Westeros 4 times and The_Vale, population 234567

Comment: Do you know how I can get rid of these repeated messages?

Comment: I just only want one Mordor is not part of Westeros and The_Vale, population 234567

Comment: @M.M I don't think I changed the type of argument, it is still `char *` , have you tried compiling?

Comment: Hold on, I will update my new code that works and what it prints

Comment: @bob0306 I do not see any code modification in the question. Please edit your code, so that I can reproduce the same output. If you feel my answer is correct, please do mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just edited the code. Do you see the for loop now? It successfully prints the message that I wanted which was The Mordor is not part of the Westeros and The_Vale, population 234567. However, it also prints The_Vale is not part of the Westeros

Comment: I think it is because when starting this code, I declare count to 5 (asking the user to enter the number of kingdoms, which I put in 5) and the for loop goes through every kingdom I typed and sees if it matches any of thie kingdom in array, but prints all the message

Comment: so is there any way I can get rid of unnecessary messages?

Comment: I don't see how you take input from user, I think you removed the 'cin' code maybe? Also, if so. Do remember you are passing count, as the second parameter.

Comment: Oh I have a cin code which is cout << "Enter # of kingdoms "; c>> count;

Comment: I don't see that in the above code, well it's a good practice to give exact code. But still, see I hope you run a loop from `0 to count - 1` and calling the diplay function.

Comment: it's not working and it keeps infinitely printing message "mordor is not part of westeros"

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
Kingdom* pKingdoms = nullptr;
pKingdoms = new Kingdom[count];
```

This creates an array with `count = 0` element. Any further access will be out of bounds.

I would advise you to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) :

```
std::vector<Kingdom> kingdoms(/*(good) count*/);
```

And a `std::string` as type of your `char m_name[32];`.

And when I see the line:

```
cout << " Searching for kingdom " << KingdomName << " in westeros " << endl;
```

I would expect something like a loop following, not a `if`. And also some code to first fill the array with some names.

After `if` => `for` edition: you should print

> KingdomName is not part of Westeros.

**after** the loop not inside, and only if `KingdomName` has not been found.

Comment: Can you look at the new edited code? It works properly the way I wanted, but it now prints unnessary messages together

Comment: @bob0306 Well, you changed your `if` to a `for`, which is good, but everything else remains.

Comment: Is there any way I can get it to make unnecessary messages without using vector stuff?

Comment: wait I don't understand After if => for edition: you should print

KingdomName << " is not part of Westeros. this part fully. Does it mean to change cout << Kingdomname << " is not part of Westeros." << endl; to KingdomName << "is not part of Westeros." ?

Comment: @bob0306 Is it better?

Comment: what do you mean by after the loop not inside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134436/discussion-between-bob0306-and-oneil).

Comment: maybe my answer is suggesting what @O'Neil is suggesting